# Rules for and list of highlighted symbols in Slime

Tags: emacs, slime

I am searching for a list of symbols which are highlighted per default in slime. Where can I find it?

Are these symbols derived from emacs lisp mode or are they defined in slime? Or are they implementation specific?

Based on which rules are certain symbols highlighted and certain not?

Thank you

Matus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out `slime-fontifying-fu.el` in SLIME distribution, as well as the contents of `lisp-mode.el` that comes with your Emacs distribution. In the beginning of `slime-fontifying-fu.el` it read as follows:

```
(:on-load
   (font-lock-add-keywords
    'lisp-mode slime-additional-font-lock-keywords)
```